# Find the$ Pr(Y\gt -0.5)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Y is distributed $t_\infty$. Find the $Pr(Y\gt -0.5)$?

This problem is really confusing. I really don't understand the t distribution and what this problem is asking. I know that the degrees of freedom is infinity but after that I'm lost. Can someone explain how I would go about solving this problem or showing me an example of something similar. I would like to try this one on my own so that I understand it. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: The t distribution with an infinite degrees of freedom is just the normal distribution.

Comment: @air How would I find the mean and standard deviations to calculate the z value? Or is the -0.5 the z value?

Comment: I think you are confusing what a z-value is, what a probability distribution is etc. z-values are usually calculated based on realized values $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ of some normal distribution. And I am afraid of answering this question of yours because I am not really sure how you interpret a z-value. (But basically, yes you could act as if $-0.5$ is the z value. But again I would feel a lot better if you showed your calculation, to avoid any misunderstanding .)

Answer (score 1):

By software, $P(Y > -.5) = 1 - P(Y \le -.5) = 0.6915.$ I will leave
it to you to get this result from printed normal tables.

To show the limit we could look at $df = 1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 100, 200, \dots$,
and find the probability of getting greater than -.5 for each $df.$
Owing to the limitations of most printed table of the t distribution,
this is a job for software (I used R):

```
 df = c(1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 1000, 10000)
 prob = 1 - pt(-.5, df)      # 1 minus CDF of t
 round(cbind(df, prob), 4)   # bind columns into array
 ##       df   prob
 ##        1 0.6476
 ##        5 0.6809
 ##       10 0.6861
 ##       20 0.6887
 ##       30 0.6896
 ##      100 0.6909
 ##      200 0.6912
 ##     1000 0.6914
 ##    10000 0.6915
```